# Set random value to password attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I tried to put a random value to a password to update it but it does not change

Controller code:

```
 @sat.password=nil
 @set=SecureRandom.hex(5)
 @sat.password=@set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you're using devise or something like that to manage passwords? You might need to do:

```
@sat.password = @sat.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.hex(5)
@sat.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey after you change some attribute of @sat you need to say `@sat.save`. Otherwise you can use update attributes...

```
@sat.update_attributes(:password => SecureRandom.hex(5))
```